# Multidimensional regression in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, regression, keras

I'm trying to implement the **One Hidden Layer Model** presented in [this](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/) article using Keras.

This is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation
from keras import optimizers

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=9216))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(30))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, verbose=0, validation_split=0.2)

y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_valid)
```

> X_train shape is (2140, 9216)
>
> y_train shape is (2140, 30)
>
> X_valid shape is (1783, 9216)

But `y_valid` shape is (1783,). I'm trying to understand why I'm not getting a (1783, 30) output. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is using `predict_classes` in:

```
model.predict_classes(X_valid)
```

this is designed to select the argmax (index of the maximum output) and choose it as the predicted class, for a classifier.

You have a regression problem, and just want the raw output from the network. So instead you should call:

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_valid)
```